# Find the area of the square

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Knowing that the area of the square below can be written as an irreducible fraction, $\frac{p}{q}$ the alternative that the sum of the digits of the number that represents the result of the expression $\frac{p-1}{q}$ is:(Answer:$5$)

[image]

I try:

$\triangle_{SED} = \frac{l.x}{2}$

$\triangle_{AEB}=\frac{l.y}{2}$

$ \triangle _{AEG}: x^2+y^2= (\frac{3\sqrt2}{2})^2 \implies x^2+y^2 = \frac{9}{2}$
[image]

Comment: Where are the points $S, E, D, A, B, G$?

Comment: Rotate the lower triangle $90^\circ$ anti-clockwise by its lower-left corner, then show that the angle between the $4$-segment and the $\frac{3\sqrt 2}{2}$-segment is $135^\circ$.

Comment: @peterwhy Sorry, missed my figure

Comment: Rotate $\triangle AEB$ $90^\circ$ anti-clockwise by $A$, then show that $\angle AED = 135^\circ$.

Comment: @AdamRubinson  I fixed the statement,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found on the net (By:castelo)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Putting the thing into cartesian coordinates, we have
$$\left\{\begin{array}*
x^2+y^2=\frac{9}{2}\\
(a-x)^2+y^2=25\\
x^2+(a-y)^2=16\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
[Thus](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D%5Cfrac%7B9%7D%7B2%7D%2C+%28a-x%29%5E2%2By%5E2%3D25%2C+x%5E2%2B%28a-y%29%5E2%3D16) $a=\sqrt{\frac{65}{2}}$.
Fine, we can walk the steps
$$\left\{\begin{array}*
x^2+y^2=\frac{9}{2}\\
(a-x)^2+y^2=25\\
x^2+(a-y)^2=16\\
\end{array}
\right.\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\left\{\begin{array}*
x^2+y^2=\frac{9}{2}\\
a^2-2ax+x^2+y^2=25\\
x^2+a^2-2ay+y^2=16\\
\end{array}
\right.\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\left\{\begin{array}*
x^2+y^2=\frac{9}{2}\\
a^2-2ax=\frac{41}{2}\\
a^2-2ay=\frac{23}{2}\\
\end{array}
\right.\Leftrightarrow$$
$$\left\{\begin{array}*
x^2+y^2=\frac{9}{2}\\
4ax=2a^2-41\\
4ay=2a^2-23\\
\end{array}
\right.\Rightarrow$$
$$16a^2\cdot\frac{9}{2}=
\left(2a^2-41\right)^2+
\left(2a^2-23\right)^2$$
$$72s=(4s^2-164s+41^2)+(4s^2-92s+23^2)$$
$$8s^2-328s+2210 = 0\Rightarrow$$
$$\left[\begin{array}*
s=\frac{17}{2}\\
s=\frac{65}{2}\\
\end{array}
\right.$$
But $\sqrt{\frac{17}{2}}<5$ is too small for fitting a segment of length $5$ inside.
Thus $s=\frac{65}{2}$

Comment: Thanks. It's correct.  $\dfrac{65-1}{2} = 32 = 3+2 = 5$

Answer (score 0):

$16+9/2-4(3\sqrt{2})\cos\theta_1=25+9/2-5(3\sqrt{2})\cos \theta_2=L^2$

$15\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_2-12\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1=9$

$\cos\theta_2=3\sqrt{2}/(10)+(4/5)\cos\theta_1$

$\cos^2\theta_2=9/50+(16/25)\cos^2\theta_1+(12\sqrt{2}/25)\cos\theta_1$

$\sin^2\theta_2=41/50-(16/25)\cos^2\theta_1-(12\sqrt{2}/25)\cos\theta_1$

$4^2+5^2-2\cdot 4\cdot 5\cos(2\pi-(\theta_1+\theta_2))=2L^2$

$41-40[\cos(\theta_1+\theta_2)]=2L^2$

$41-40(\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2)=2L^2$

$\cos\theta_1\cos\theta_2=3\sqrt{2}/10\cos\theta_1+(4/5)\cos^2\theta_1$

$\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2=\sin\theta_1\sqrt{41/50-(16/25)\cos^2\theta_1-(12\sqrt{2}/25)\cos\theta_1}$

$41-40([(3\sqrt{2}/10)\cos\theta_1]+(4/5)\cos^2\theta_1]-[\sin\theta_1\sqrt{41/50-(16/25)\cos^2\theta_1-(12\sqrt{2}/25)\cos\theta_1}])=32+9-24\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1$

$12\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1+32\cos^2\theta_1+40\sin\theta_1\sqrt{41/50-(16/25)\cos^2\theta_1-(12\sqrt{2}/25)\cos\theta_1}=24\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1$

$-12\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1+32\cos^2\theta_1=-40\sin\theta_1\sqrt{41/50-(16/25)\cos^2\theta_1-(12\sqrt{2}/25)\cos\theta_1}$

$288\cos^2\theta_1+1024\cos^4\theta_1-24\cdot32\sqrt{2}\cos^3\theta_1=1600(1-\cos^2\theta_1)[(41/50)-(16/25)\cos^2\theta_1-(12\sqrt{2}/25)\cos\theta_1]$

$288\cos^2\theta_1+1024\cos^4\theta_1-24\cdot32\sqrt{2}\cos^3\theta_1=(1-\cos^2\theta_1)[32\cdot 41-1024\cos^2\theta_1-64\cdot 12\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1]$

$9\cos^2\theta_1+32\cos^4\theta_1-24\sqrt{2}\cos^3\theta_1=(1-\cos^2\theta_1)[41-32\cos^2\theta_1-24\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1]$

$9\cos^2\theta_1+32\cos^4\theta_1-24\sqrt{2}\cos^3\theta_1=41-32\cos^2\theta_1-24\sqrt{2}\cos\theta_1-41\cos^2\theta_1+32\cos^4\theta_1+24\sqrt{2}\cos^3\theta_1$

$0=41-82\cos^2\theta_1+48\sqrt{2}\cos^3\theta_1$

Now solve the cubic for $\cos\theta_1$. That will give you $\cos\theta_2$ and $L^2$.